# How to simultaneously load 2 completely different urdf in robot_description param

Tags: ros, urdf, ros-melodic, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to spawn 2 different robots. one is a DRONE and another is a MOBILE ROVER. Both have no joint mutual in between. I need to control them via ROS simultaneously. The major problem is I cannot use robot_description to load both urdf sequentially because later overwrites initial. Is there any way to spawn them together? Or please tell me if I should approach it differently.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381836/how-to-simultaneously-load-2-completely-different-urdf-in-robot_description-param/) by [bolu](https://answers.ros.org/users/55620/bolu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So here is the thing `robot_description` is just a normal variable on the parameter server, we can even use `red_banana` to define another robot_description file on the parameter server. The thing is we need to remap it to `robot_description` in the particular node we use it in because most of the nodes use `robot_description` as a parameter to get a current robot state. Below is an example of the same.

---

```
<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="banana_state_publisher" >
  <remap from="robot_description" to="banana_robot_description" />
  <remap from="joint_states" to="curdbot_joint_states" />
</node>


<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="mango_state_publisher" >
  <remap from="robot_description" to="mango_robot_description" />
  <remap from="joint_states" to="catbot_joint_states" />
</node>

<node name="mango_joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" respawn="false" output="screen">
<remap from="robot_description" to="/mango_robot_description" />
<remap from="joint_states" to="mango_joint_states" />
</node>
<node name="banana_joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" respawn="false" output="screen">
<remap from="robot_description" to="/banana_robot_description" />
<remap from="joint_states" to="banana_joint_states" />
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [bolu](https://answers.ros.org/users/55620/bolu/) with karma: 11 on 2021-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-08-01**:
It would be cleaner and more ros-like if you create a `namespace` for each robot using a `group` tag. See http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#Tag_Reference.

Independent of my first comment, don't forget you'll also need to avoid collisions between the Transform Frame names.

**Comment by [Sid05](https://answers.ros.org/users/94909/sid05/) on 2022-06-23**:
Hi,

So I had the same problem , the answer from @bolu works.
Just as a note to someone facing the same issue , make sure the param name that you use while loading the URDF into ROS parameter server matches the name to which you remap to in both joint_state_publisher and robot_state_publisher package